# Create generic repository for returning data from stored procedure with EFCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to create a generic custom repository using the aspnetboilerplate framework. I want the repository to be able to call a stored procedure in SQL Server and return a set of data for use with an explicit type.

Custom repository:

```
public class PMStoredProcedureRepository<T> : IPMStoredProcedureRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private MyDbContext Context { get; set; }

    public PMStoredProcedureRepository(IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        Context = dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();
    }

    // When you expect a model back (async)
    public IQueryable<T> ExecuteSP(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var type = Context.Set<T>().FromSql(query, parameters);
        return type;
    }
}
```

What my app service looks like:

```
public class DashboardAppService : MyAppServiceBase, IDashboardAppService
{
    // Entity repositories
    private readonly IPMStoredProcedureRepository<PMTestSP> _storedProcRepository;

    public DashboardAppService(
        IPMStoredProcedureRepository<PMTestSP> storedProcRepository
        )
    {
        _storedProcRepository = storedProcRepository;
    }

    public List<PMTestSP> GetTestSP()
    {
        var ret = _storedProcRepository.ExecuteSP("exec pme_TestProcedure", new SqlParameter("inputString", "abcde"));
        return ret.ToList();
    }
}
```

I added the return type to the DbContext as:

```
public virtual DbSet<PMTestSP> PMTestSP { get; set; }
```

When I call GetTestSP, I get this error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name:
>   unitOfWork
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkExtensions.GetDbContext(IActiveUnitOfWork
>   unitOfWork, Nullable multiTenancySide)
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider.GetDbContext(Nullable
>   multiTenancySide)
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider.GetDbContext()
>   Company.Name.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.PMStoredProcedureRepository..ctor(IDbContextProvider
>   dbContextProvider) in PMStoredProcedureRepository.cs
>   +
>               Context = dbContextProvider.GetDbContext(); Castle.Proxies.PMStoredProcedureRepository`1Proxy..ctor(IInterceptor[]
>   , IDbContextProvider )

Comment: There's an article on how to execute a stored procedure with APB. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1199648/Using-Stored-Procedure-User-Defined-Function-and-V

Comment: That article ties the repository to an explicit type, <user>. I'm hoping to keep the repository generic to typify it when calling stored procs, matching the return from the procedure with an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[UnitOfWork]` attribute and make it a `virtual` method:

```
[UnitOfWork]
public virtual List<PMTestSP> GetTestSP()
{
    // ...
}
```

You can inject `IUnitOfWorkManager` to begin a `UnitOfWork` explicitly:

```
public List<PMTestType> GetTestSP()
{
    using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
        var ret = _storedProcRepository.ExecuteSP("exec pme_TestProcedure", new SqlParameter("inputString", "abcde"));
        uow.Complete();
        return ret.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your custom repository don't get right dbcontext. Look at document [Create custom repository](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EntityFramework-Integration#DocCustomRepositoryMethods)

```
public class SimpleTaskSystemRepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : EfRepositoryBase<SimpleTaskSystemDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    public SimpleTaskSystemRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<SimpleTaskSystemDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
    }

    //add common methods for all repositories
}
```

**Note:** the custom repository must inherit `EfRepositoryBase<SimpleTaskSystemDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey>`. You could try this.